# Racket: Map rest arguments to another procedure

Tags: plot, scheme, racket, map-function

I'm trying to take a list of rest parameters and map them to a list of arguments for the [`plot`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/) procedure in Racket, but I've been having poor luck for some reason.

```
(define (graph fn/1
               #:grid? [grid? true] 
               #:min [min -20] 
               #:max [max 20]
               . fns)
   (define plot-input 
           (list (axes)
                 (if grid? (tick-grid) empty)
                 (function identity #:style 'dot #:width 1.5 #:color 'gray)
                 (function fn/1)
                 ;; would like (function f) for each f in fns iff fns exists
   ))
   (plot plot-input
         #:x-min min
         #:x-max max
         #:y-min min
         #:y-max max))
```

Comment: I guess Scheme and Racket are not Lisps? If this is indeed the consensus, could you please make this official and tell us this in no uncertain terms. I sometimes add "lisp" tag to "scheme" tagged questions. Should I never do this anymore, or it can sometimes be justified? I'm confused. @RainerJoswig  thanks.

Comment: @WillNess: there is no need to tag all kinds questions of Lisp-related languages with the Lisp-tag. Shouldn't we tag all Logo questions with Lisp? Use the Lisp tag if it helps to find/answer a question - for example if the question is general enough, that it would be relevant for non-Racket users. There is no need to tag a really Racket-specific question with R6RS, Scheme, Lisp, Programming Language, s-expression language, and similar tags. My proposal: use the Lisp tag to signal general Lisp content, not to signal that the language used is a Lisp-dialect.

Comment: OK, thanks, makes sense. OTOH Common Lisp too has `list*` and `map`, so it's kind of general.... Sometiems it's hard to tell if it's too specific or not....

Comment: @WillNess: generally you will always find some similar names. Seeing that it does the same and that it works in the context of the code example (function, define, Racket arglists, Racket calling conventions, ...), requires specific Racket knowhow. It would also ideally require to a) read Racket docs and/or b) try the solution example in Racket. Personally I try to run all the code solutions I propose in the specific mentioned system or some equivalent - which here is only Racket itself. Attracting half-baked answers from people who don't know Racket and don't use it, is not so desirable, IMHO.

Comment: @Willness: if the question requires you to write code that is specific to a particular language, then it is not a general Lisp question. Otherwise one might answer this question with Clojure code - which would only be semi-helpful.

Comment: @RainerJoswig "if the question requires you to write code that is specific to a particular language, then it is not a general Lisp question." this is a useful rule of thumb, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `map`:

```
   (define plot-input 
           (list* (axes)
                  (if grid? (tick-grid) empty)
                  (function identity #:style 'dot #:width 1.5 #:color 'gray)
                  (function fn/1)
                  ;; would like (function f) for each f in fns iff fns exists
                  (map function fns)
   ))
```

Uses [`list*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list*#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%2A%29%29) to splice in the list of results produced by `map`, instead of the original `list`.